# What is the difference between route and netstat?

Tags: networking, router, netstat

It seems that `route` and `netstat` return almost the same results. What is the difference between them? Why are there two commands giving redundant results? Isn't it better to consolidate the duplication into just a single command?

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
10.6.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.128.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
10.10.0.0       10.6.0.1        255.255.0.0     UG    1000   0        0 tun0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
$ netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.6.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.128.0   U         0 0          0 tun0
10.10.0.0       10.6.0.1        255.255.0.0     UG        0 0          0 tun0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

Comment: I think you answered your own question - the difference is minimal (with the parameters you posted), but there still is a difference. Also see below.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to assume a central decision-making authority that simply does not exist.

Developers create what they want to create...or what they are paid to create. Those tools were written by different people at different times who had different goals.

You are welcome to reach out to both authors, and try to persuade them to unify their efforts. Since there is no central authority, nobody else will do it for you.

Comment: Where are the official repos for each? There are different flavors of each. I don't know where are the repos for ubuntu.

Comment: That's a separate, non-trivial question. Please remember that AskUbuntu uses a Question/Answer format. It's not a threaded discussion forum.